# Booked a ticket on Lufthansa two weeks ago, credit card not charged yet

Tags: air-travel, bookings, payment-cards, lufthansa

I booked a ticket on Lufthansa website to weeks ago, my flight will be next November.
I got a confirmation code and an eticket number.

Until now the price of the ticket was not charged to my credit card. I checked with Lufthansa, they said it was OK, I checked with my bank and they said they don't see the transactions in their records.

Has anybody been through a similar situation before? I just want to avoid any surprises on the flight day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I often book online tickets from Lufthansa and I also find it strange, but it often takes several weeks before my selected mean of payment is actually charged. This has never caused any problems.

Even if you are not a registered user, you can use their ['My Bookings'](https://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/de/my_account/mybookings?l=en) page and with your last name and booking number retrieve your ticket and verify yourself that everything is ok.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just worried because the transaction didn't appear at all on my online banking records, was it like that with you?

Comment: I usually pay with direct debit and not with credit card, but as I said, it usually take several weeks before the bank account, or in your case the credit card, is actually charged. Until the charge, you will not see it in your banking records.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll keep you updated once the transaction takes place

Comment: Hi, finally Lufthansa charged my credit card after nearly 3 weeks. It seems that they delay charges for some reason.